# How do I declare an array of red black trees?

Tags: d

When I want to initialize a red black tree I do as in the documentation.

```
auto rbt = redBlackTree(1,2,3,4)
```

but if I want to declare it globally or make an array of red black trees I don't know how to do it and the documentation is not helping. I've tried various things and I frequently get errors similar to: `redBlackTree!int is used as a type` Can you help me? I could do it if I knew what to put instead of `auto`, ie, if I knew the type of `redBlackTree`.

I want to declare a red black tree in global scope or declare an array for which I need to declare the type, I want to do something like this:

```
type rbt;
void main() {
    rbt.insert(3);
}
```

or this:

```
void main{
    type[2] rbt;
    rbt[0].insert(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type (using long instead of int) is `RedBlackTree!long`, here are some examples. Remember you have to use `new` to initialize the class.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.container;

RedBlackTree!long rbtree;
RedBlackTree!long[2] rbarray;
RedBlackTree!long[] rbdynamicarr;
RedBlackTree!long[][] rbmat;

void main() {
    rbtree.writeln;
    rbtree = new RedBlackTree!long;
    rbtree.insert(3);
    rbtree.writeln;

    rbarray.writeln;
    rbarray = new RedBlackTree!long[2];
    rbarray.writeln;

    rbdynamicarr.writeln;
    int n = 3;
    rbdynamicarr = new RedBlackTree!long[n];
    rbdynamicarr.writeln;

    rbmat.writeln;
    int m = 2;
    rbmat = new RedBlackTree!long[][](n,m);
    rbmat.writeln;

    alias RBTree = typeof(redBlackTree!long(1L));
    RBTree rbalias;
    rbalias = new RBTree;
    rbalias.writeln;

    RBTree[3] crayola;
    crayola.writeln;

    typeid(redBlackTree(1)).writeln;
    RedBlackTree!(long, "a < b", false) hola;
    hola = new RedBlackTree!(long, "a < b", false);
    hola.writeln;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the type of `redBlackTree`. You can query for at compile-time with `typeof`:

```
alias RBTree = typeof(redBlackTree(1));
RBTree rbt = redBlackTree(1, 2, 3);
```

This is a common and an encouraged pattern as many functions in D return [Voldemort types](https://wiki.dlang.org/Voldemort_types) (types that cannot be named).

In your example the type is `RedBlackTree!int`. If you don't use an IDE, an easy way to discover the type is `pragma(msg, typeof(<functionCall>(<args>)));`.
Furthermore, I should note that declaring an array of RedBlackTree works with `auto`:

```
auto arr = [redBlackTree(1, 2), redBlackTree(3, 4)];
```

For more help, please feel free to post the exact code that failed.

Comment: I want to declare a red black tree in global scope or an array of red black trees like this: `type[2] rbt_array;` where type is the type of the red black tree

Comment: A static array with two elements would be declared as `RBTree[2] r = [redBlackTree(1, 2), redBlackTree(3, 4)];` or you a bit more comfortable `auto r = [redBlackTree(1, 2), redBlackTree(3, 4)].staticArray`. The type of both assignments is `RedBlackTree!(int, "a < b", false)[2]`. You can see both examples at https://run.dlang.io/is/BiyozZ.